# How to jump over an input command and continue the script in Python, if the input isn't given?

Tags: python

I am trying to write a jump over command in Python.

The code needs to include `input ('Press enter ...')` command, but if the input isn't given at a certain time, it needs to jump over the input section and continue the code as if the input was given. How do I do this??

Example:

```
input("To start a loop press Enter:") 

for x in range 10
    print (x)

print("loop trough")
```

Comment: Please add some more context/code.

Comment: please see if this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1335507/keyboard-input-with-timeout-in-python

Comment: and this one too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2933399/how-to-set-time-limit-on-input

Comment: Duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2831775/running-a-python-script-for-a-user-specified-amount-of-time

Comment: Long and short of the duplicates is "This is incredibly hard to do on Windows"

Answer (score 0):

How about using a daemon thread and a queue? Ugly solution I know, but should work everywhere.

```
from threading import Thread
from collections import deque
from time import sleep


def get_user_input(statement, queue):

    res = input(statement)
    queue.append(res)


if __name__ == '__main__':

    queue = deque()
    t = Thread(
        target=get_user_input,
        args=('Enter something: ', queue),
        daemon=True,
    )

    t.start()
    sleep(5)

    if len(queue) > 0:
        print('input received')
    else:
        print('no input received')
```