# Python run Subprocess for certain time

Tags: python

I'm testing a certain exe file, and I want to implement a way for my script to determine that it has entered an infinite loop.
This is my current code:

```
import subprocess
import os
import sys
runs = 1000 # Default run is 1000
if len(sys.argv)>1: # If I want to change the num of runs
    runs = int(sys.argv[1])
FNULL = open(os.devnull, 'w')
logfile = open('logfile', 'w')
args = "exe" # Exe to test
succ = 0
fail = 0
for i in range (0,runs):
    if subprocess.call(args,stdout = logfile, stderr = FNULL) == 100:
        succ += 1 # If returned 100 then success
    else:
        fail += 1 # Else Failed
        break # Break on failure
    open('logfile', 'w').close() # Empties the file
print "Succ: %d , Fail: %d" % (succ, fail)
```

Lets say I define an infinite loop as my exe running for longer than 5 seconds.
How would i go about implementing this?
Thanks for any help, including tips on the current code!

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2831775/running-a-python-script-for-a-user-specified-amount-of-time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start a `threading.Timer` that will kill the process after 5 seconds and report back that the deed was done. You'll need to create and wait for the process in different steps, so use the `Popen` object instead of `call`. I created a test program that uses sleep to simulate your inifinite list.

```
import subprocess
import os
import sys
import threading

def on_timeout(proc, status_dict):
    """Kill process on timeout and note as status_dict['timeout']=True"""
    # a container used to pass status back to calling thread
    status_dict['timeout'] = True
    print("timed out")
    proc.kill()

runs = 1000 # Default run is 1000
if len(sys.argv)>1: # If I want to change the num of runs
    runs = int(sys.argv[1])
FNULL = open(os.devnull, 'w')
logfile = open('logfile', 'w')
# replacing example with a running program. This is a simple python
# we can call from the command line.
# args = "exe" # Exe to test
test_script = "import time;import sys;time.sleep(%d);sys.exit(100)"
succ = 0
fail = 0
for i in range (0,runs):
    # set by timer 
    status_dict = {'timeout':False}
    # test prog sleeps i seconds
    args = ["python", "-c", test_script % i]
    proc = subprocess.Popen(args, 
        stdout = logfile, stderr = FNULL)
    # trigger timout and kill process in 5 seconds
    timer = threading.Timer(5, on_timeout, (proc, status_dict))
    timer.start()
    proc.wait()
    # in case we didn't hit timeout
    timer.cancel()
    print status_dict
    if not status_dict['timeout'] and proc.returncode == 100:
        succ += 1 # If returned 100 then success
    else:
        fail += 1 # Else Failed
        break # Break on failure
    open('logfile', 'w').close() # Empties the file
print "Succ: %d , Fail: %d" % (succ, fail)
```

Comment: This looks amazing! A question though, you write: "#test prog sleeps i seconds" . Isn't i the iterator over which run i am? so i'll sleep for longer the farther in I am?

Comment: i is the ongoing result of the iterator... Not sure what you call it except an iterated value... . When you run it, tests run progressively longer until the time hits. It's just a test case I cooked up to make sure the code works.

Comment: so if i wanted to always run for 5 seconds i should just change to : proc = subprocess.Popen(["python", "-c", test_script%5],...    ?

Comment: I'm also confused as to where i should call my exe?

Comment: You replace my python test script. I'll update the post to make it more clear.

Answer (score 2):

In python3.3 timeout was added to subprocess.call. If you are using python3.3 then you can just change your subprocess.call to have timeout as argument:

```
   subprocess.call(args,stdout = logfile, stderr = FNULL, timeout=5)
```

If you are using python2.7, you can either use [subprocess32](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/subprocess32/) package or you need to write some extra code to handle the timeout.

If you install subprocess32 module you can use the above method of subprocess.call with timeout as argument.

Else, this code can help you achieve the same functionality:

```
from subprocess import Popen
timeout=5 #5 seconds
p = Popen(args, shell = True, stdout = logfile, stderr = FNULL)
while (p.poll() is None and timeout > 0):
    time.sleep(1)
    timeout-=1

if timeout <= 0:
    p.terminate()  #Timeout
```

Comment: This looks very simple! Thanks I'll try this!

Comment: So while this does work, it can't be used on a very large set. For instance running the code 10,000 times requires 10,000 seconds at least.

Comment: Yes. Sleep is not affordable when there are numerous runs. Having a separate timer thread is better.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

```
import subprocess
import time

for _ in range(999999): # or whatever
    p1 = subprocess.Popen(['exe_file', 'arg1', 'arg2'])
    time.sleep(0.1)  # wait a small amount of time, hopefully the process ends fast
    return_code = p1.poll()

    if return_code is not None: # we're happy, the process ended fast
        ... # do something to celebrate
    else:  # we're sad. let the process run for at most 5 seconds
        time.sleep(5)   
        p1.terminate()    # this kills the process. try p1.kill() too...
        p1.wait()   #  this cleans up the process registry.
```

Disclaimer: this is linux code. Things could be different on windows, but you can check this out first, and then read some stuff here https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html    about the subprocess library and differences between linux and windows.