# Python Selenium: How to get fresh data from the page get refreshed periodically?

Tags: python, ajax, selenium

I have already written a script that opens Firefox with a URL, scrape data and close. The page belongs to a gaming site where page refresh contents via Ajax.

Now one way is to fetch those AJAX requests and get data or refresh page after certain period of time within open browser.

For the later case, how should I do? Should I call the method after certain time period or what?

Answer (score 0):

You can implement so-called `smart wait`.

1. Indicate the most frequently updating and useful for you web element
   at the page
2. Get data from it by using JavaScript since DOM model will not be updated without page refresh, eg:

   `driver.execute_script('document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML')`
3. Wait for certain time, get it again and compare with previous result. If changed - refresh page, fetch data, etc.

Comment: Will there be need of page refresh or Selenium will get *updated* DOM? Something like this? http://scrolltest.com/python/using-wait-with-selenium-in-python/

Comment: @Volatil3, nope, DOM model will not be updated. Thanks, for good question. I updated my answer. Please, share with me result after investigation

Answer (score 0):

You can use the time library to do it. For example:

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Firefox()

while <condicion>:
  driver.get("http://www.url.org")
  # extract and save data
  time.sleep(5000) # whaits 5000 seconds

driver.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to call `findElement()` again after waiting, bc otherwise you might not get a fresh instance. Or use page factory, which will get a fresh copy of the `WebElement` for you every time the instance is accessed.

Answer (score 0):

Try with refresh the page time by time to get the updated result.

```
  driver.navigate().refresh();
```

To refresh page in a period of time refer below link :-

[Running a python script for a user-specified amount of time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2831775/running-a-python-script-for-a-user-specified-amount-of-time)

Hope it will help you :)