# make python script run for a minute

Tags: python, time, scripting

I'm working on a small project where the script is to monitor user's keyboard inputs and I only want the script to run for a duration of 1 minute. After that minute has passed, I want a final print statement of the inputs and to terminate the script. The time.sleep function is not a viable choice here since I want to update variables and receive output for every action, and using sleep will only delay each input.

```
from pynput import keyboard

word_counter = 0


def on_press(key):
    global word_counter
    try:
        print('alphabet key {} pressed'.format(key.char))
    except AttributeError:
        if key == keyboard.Key.space:
            word_counter += 1
            print(word_counter)
        elif key == keyboard.Key.esc:
            return False
        print('special key {} pressed'.format(key))


with keyboard.Listener(on_press=on_press) as listener:
    listener.join()

# After a minute, this will be the final output and the program will terminate
print('You typed a total of {} words in a minute'.format(word_counter))
```

Comment: Well, which part should be running for 1 minute? I can't understand what this code is..

Comment: The whole script should run for 1 minute. The code is basically just monitoring my inputs. After a duration I want to terminate the whole program.

Comment: You might find answers, that might help you with your problem here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2831775/running-a-python-script-for-a-user-specified-amount-of-time

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This will be the answer:

```
from pynput import keyboard
import threading, time

word_counter = 0

def background():
    def on_press(key):
        global word_counter
        try:
            print('alphabet key {} pressed'.format(key.char))
        except AttributeError:
            if key == keyboard.Key.space:
                word_counter += 1
                print(word_counter)
            elif key == keyboard.Key.esc:
                return False
            print('special key {} pressed'.format(key))

    with keyboard.Listener(on_press=on_press) as listener:
        listener.join()

def wait():
    time.sleep(60)

background = threading.Thread(name = 'background', target = background)
background.start()
wait()

# After a minute, this will be the final output and the program will terminate
print('You typed a total of {} words in a minute'.format(word_counter))
```

Comment: This worked! Thanks, I knew it had to do with threading but just didn't know how to implement it in my project.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!

Comment: Why isn't it working for me? Mac, Python 2.7. Recognizes special characters but even if I type dozens of words within given time, program ends up saying 0 words. And it doesn't terminate after 60 seconds. Continue to recognize special keys if I press any of them (e.g. cmd, ctrl etc.)

Comment: @bisherbas Well, I think that python version matters. I ran this program with Python 3.5. How about trying that program with upgraded version? If it doesn't work again, tell me anytime

Comment: @HoseongJeon Unfortunately same behavior with Python 3.7

Comment: @bisherbas Did you install pynput? What error comes out?

Comment: @bisherbas not a mistake on your part. There was still a little fixing to do. A simple if/else around the content of the on_press function did the trick, and returning false when the program is done.

Comment: @HoseongJeon Yes I did install pynput. Without it I would have had bunch of errors. But like I said there are no errors. Script didn't work the way it's supposed to. Thanks for the feedback user3152311. I guess I might need to modify to code a little bit to make it work.

Answer (score 1):

```
from pynput import keyboard
import time

word_counter = 0


def on_press(key):
    global word_counter
    try:
        print('alphabet key {} pressed'.format(key.char))
    except AttributeError:
        if key == keyboard.Key.space:
            word_counter += 1
            print(word_counter)
        elif key == keyboard.Key.esc:
            return False
        print('special key {} pressed'.format(key))
i=int(time.time())+60
while(time.time()<=i):
     with keyboard.Listener(on_press=on_press) as listener:
          listener.join()

# After a minute, this will be the final output and the program will terminate
print('You typed a total of {} words in a minute'.format(word_counter))
```

i believe this code will run for 1 minute.

eg:

```
import time 

i=int(time.time())+60
print("ddnd")
while(int(time.time())<=i):
    print("dlksnd")
```