# Python Condition Based on Time

Tags: python-3.x

I don't even know how to go about writing this, but will give it a shot.  Don't beat me up too badly :-D

I'm using Python3 and want to write a condition based on time.

If current price is below a certain price for 1 minute, I want to sale.

```
if num1 < num2:
   print("NUM1 has been LESS THAN NUM2 for 1 minute")
```

I'm stuck on including the time portion for this.

Comment: How are you getting the time and where is it compared to?

Comment: An [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51222124/15745884) in this stack thread would be helpful -- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51221962/make-python-script-run-for-a-minute.  The solution will look something like this - wrap the print statement in a while loop based a time condition.

Comment: I've imported time and datetime.  Not sure if these are ones I can use for what I'm trying to accomplish or not.  Just been playing around with it trying to figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

This solution is drawn from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51221962/make-python-script-run-for-a-minute) ***Stack Overflow*** thread. The answer was given by [Nithish Albin](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51222124/15745884)

Here, you use the `time` import. When your `if` condition results to true, the `print` statement is executed followed by the `while` loop
which waits for a minute(does nothing). The condition for `while` loop to terminate is that the current time should be less than `i` (60 seconds in the future).

```
import time

num1 = 1
num2 = 2
i=int(time.time())+60  # setting a checkpoint 60s in the future
if num1 < num2:
    print("NUM1 has been LESS THAN NUM2 for 1 minute")
    while(int(time.time())<=i): # checking if the current time is past the checkpoint "i"
        pass
```

Comment: This will print statement multiple times, since its under while loop

Comment: Thanks for bringing it to my notice. I have made the changes.

Answer (score 0):

One simple way to achieve this using **while** loop

```
import time

condition = True

num1 = 10
num2 = 11
t = time.time()

while condition == True:
    t1 = time.time()
    if num1 < num2:
        if t1 - t > 60:
            print("NUM1 has been LESS THAN NUM2 for 1 minute")
            condition = False

            #print(t1-t)
```